# Click on chart bar and update card

Tags: xml, annotations, sapui5, hana, sap-fiori

When I click on a bar on the first (bar) chart I want to update the results on the second (donut) chart.

I don't understand a lot of fiori in general, so I'm really lost. I already have the donut chart done, but I want to update it when I click on a bar of the bar chart.

I'm doing the charts and working with annotations.

I've been trying the options DataFieldForIntentBasedNavigation and DataFieldForAction with String="{@i18n>DONUTCENTRO}" (DONUTCENTRO = my second chart and the one I have to update)

Is there a way of doing this?

If you need any more information I'll try to provide it.

This is the page. The second chart doesn't appear right now because I can't update it.
[image: Page]

Can somebody please help?

Comment: I try to understand the issue:
Are these 2 charts on an Overview Page?

Comment: +SAP Fiori Crew I added a print screen to the question of the page. I'm new to fiori, but I think it is an Overview Page